# Cleverly disable options 'cache' in Bundle View block

Tags: blocks

I have an interesting use case for disabling a Bundle's options 'cache':

**Controller:**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    Mage::register('my_flag',true);
    //...other stuff
}
```

**app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Block/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php:**

```
#class rewrite of Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle
public function getOptions()
{
    if (!$this->_options || Mage::registry('my_flag')) { // this is the undesired hack
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance(true);
        $typeInstance->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);

        $optionCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsCollection($product);

        $selectionCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection(
            $typeInstance->getOptionsIds($product),
            $product
        );

        $this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false,
            Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck()
        );
    }

    return $this->_options;
}
```

Currently I'm rewriting this and requiring it to fetch/append from the collection if a `Mage::registry` value exists. This feels.... messy.

I'd love a **clever** solution that **doesn't require me** to set a `Mage::registry` value in the controller. I considered forcing the view to set `$this->_options` to `null`: but I'd rather the rewrite, quite honestly, than have that sort of logic in the view.

**Edit:**

From the same Bundle.php rewrite:

```
public function getProduct() {
    if (!$this->hasData('product') || Mage::registry('my_flag')) { // same hack
        $product = Mage::registry('product');
        if (is_null($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getStoreFilter($product))) {
            $product->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore(), $product);
        }
        $this->setData('product', $product);
    }
    return $this->getData('product');
}
```

Comment: Are you using registry to provide controller-calculated value to the view?

Comment: What's the condition for setting the registry value? It might help to post a bit more of what your custom code does to have a bit more context.

Comment: If accessing a particular route, we flag in the app (via registry) to handle some display logic. Essentially build a multi-bundle pricing component on a custom product page. This allows us to track selections, pricing of potentially dozens of bundle items on one page while still utilizing the default Magento options behavior. However, when building out the options html for secondary, tertiary (and so on) products on the page they are reflecting the base product's bundle options and not their own (due to the options cache).

Comment: Can't you use a different instance of the block `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle` for each product? O simply create you own class that extends the block mentioned above, where you can add a method `resetOptions(){$this->_options = null}` that you can call after rendering each product.

Comment: > "Can't you use a different instance of the block" // but dat block cache doe. No, but seriously, not a horrible suggestion but would require us to build the block programmatically instead of in layout xml. I like that train of thought, however...

Comment: How does `$this->getProduct()` know which to render if it's not a separate instance of the block? Unless you're doing `$childBlock->setProduct($_product)` while looping through the list of bundle products you're rendering.

Comment: LOL I have to just keep adding code. See edit.

Comment: @beeplogic One of the challenges is that much of the other logic around bundles relies on Mage::registry('current_product') - which means in the case of this page unregistering and re-registering. I hope that answers your question. Yes the register is happening in a loop; but from a collection, not successive Mage::getModel calls.

Comment: It occurs to me that this is hint of some cleanup needed in the implementation higher in the stack; for instance generating the blocks programmatically with createBlock('foo/bar')->setProduct($product) rather than relying on register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a custom layout handle to work with, it might be possible to `<reference>` the block and set a flag there. It wont prevent you from having to rewrite the block type class but at least you avoid using the registry.

**Controller**:

```
$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('custom_bundle_view');
```

**local.xml or custom module's layout XML file:**

```
<custom_bundle_view>
    <reference name="product.info.bundle">
        <action method="setSkipOptionsCache"><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
<custom_bundle_view>
```

**app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Block/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php:**

`if (!$this->_options || $this->getSkipOptionsCache()) {`

Comment: Great minds think alike - this was the first approach (much like the addRenderer methods in the same bundle blocks) ... I like this and it would be useful if this were the only place we had to perform the change; in that case the registry is more expressive because we don't have to apply it to two other blocks. But I do like this. Upboats.